# Export "MyModule" is not defined - on Jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to selectively export this module, which fails on tests, and export a blank module otherwise (so that tests don't complain). Following this SO answer: [Skip import when react component created by jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553173/skip-import-when-react-component-created-by-jest?noredirect=1#comment99687823_56553173)

```
let Analytics;
let Segment;
if (process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID == undefined){
  Analytics = require('@segment/analytics.js-core');
  Segment = require('@segment/analytics.js-integration-segmentio');
}
else {
  // If we're testing...
  Analytics = {
    page() {},
    track() {},
    identify() {},
    initialize() {},
    addIntegration() {},
  };
  Segment = {};
}    
console.log(Analytics);
export {Analytics};
```

If I remove the export, that console.log() line gets me this when I run jest tests:

```
{ page: [Function: page],
  track: [Function: track],
  identify: [Function: identify],
  initialize: [Function: initialize],
  addIntegration: [Function: addIntegration] }
```

However, when I have the export, I get this issue:

```
SyntaxError: index.js: Export 'Analytics' is not defined (36:8)
```

Is there another way I should be exporting? Any idea why I'm getting this syntax error? I'll mention that when running my app which does this import locally, everything works fine.

Comment: How are you importing?

Comment: import {Analytics} from 'path/to/file';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly naming the export when you export it, so

```
export { Analytics as Analytics };
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed :)